# How i can delete a div based with a specific classname on clicking of delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongoose

I'm retrieving data from `database` using `mongoose` which follows

**Schema** as `{name:String,image: String}`
**Stored** in `mongodb` as `{_id:327asgjgasjfg7,name:String,image: String}`

Everytime I enter some data to form it is stored in database dynamically and bellow is my code for creation of thumbnail according to my data from database

I have added a **Delete** `button` wrapped to `caption` and `image` and I want to delete the whole div with class="col-lg-3" on clicking of button. I don't want to delete the data from database which I have already done.
[Project files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RngA7GaSEKNkZrcms1cVRSNGc/view?usp=sharing)

```
<div class="container text:center" style="display: flex ; flex-wrap: wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <% for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ %> 
      <div class="col-lg-3" id=<%data[i].id%> >  <!-- here we created column with camp_id  -->  
         <div class="img-thumbnail">
           <img  src=<%= data[i].image %>>
             <div class="caption">
               <h4><%= data[i].name %></h4>
             </div>
             <div class="Remove">
               <a href="/<%=data[i].id%>" type="button" class="rmv_btn btn btn-primary">Remove </a>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      <% } %>
   </div>
```

Comment: add rendered HTML and also included all relevant code

Comment: Use `$(".col-lg-3").remove();` in jQuery to remove all div's with the class `col-lg-3` applied. But I would suggest to remove div elements by id like `$("#camp_id").remove();`

Comment: now i have added the complete project files on gdrive

Comment: use `$(this).closest('.col-lg-3').remove();`

Comment: thnks it worked

Answer (score 1):

Thnks guradio  your solution was `$(this).closest('.col-lg-3').remove();` and it worked.`